# Get value of Ace.js editor in golang

Tags: javascript, html, go, server, editor

I'm here again to clear something. I got a html page running with golang with an embed Ace.js editor and what I look for is to get the editor's string content value and play with it inside golang to analize it. The question is, how I do that? I previously  worked it on javascript and it was as easy to do as this:

```
  let editor = ace.edit(0);
  let value_Txt = editor.getSession().getValue();
```

I will appreciate your help since I recently started working on golang

Answer (score 1):

I guess that Golang, in this case, is only responsible for rendering the page. From that moment onwards, Ace.js will run in the client's browser.

You won't get the content of the page until you submit it through an API (e.g. using `POST`) and do something with it. What you were doing in JS before still applies now.